# Get string of all possible characters given iOS keyboard language

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to verify that every character in a text box is limited to the language's keyboard options. This means that in English, you would only be able to type characters which are accessible through the iOS keyboard. If there is a string containing all characters, or a code solution - either will work.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can create a regex for that.

Comment: The user can change keyboard language at any time while typing. Which keyboard are you intending to limit them to? (It would be very useful to understand the goal here. Why would a user want this feature?)

Comment: @RobNapier For example, if my language is set to German, I would only want German characters in the keyboard set allowed to be entered.

Comment: On the English keyboard, I can type Ę, which is not an English character. Do you intend that to be legal? And if `Locale.current.languageCode` is `de`, but the user's keyboard is Arabic, you want to block them typing entirely?

Comment: Yes, that Ę should be legal. If language is set to de and they have an arabic keyboard, they shouldn't be able to type any character that isn't part of the `de` characters set

Comment: @rezon iOS doesn't provide that kind of information about the keyboards. You would have to build a character set for each keyboard you want to check. This question is particularly complex on East Asian keyboards that allow hand writing. I'm still fascinated to understand what the goal is here.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Let me know if it helped :) Good luck!

```
    let letters = CharacterSet.letters
    let text = textField.text
    let range = text.rangeOfCharacters(from: letters)
    if range != nil {
      // Yay it's correct
    }else{
      // Oh no
    }
```

The CharacterSet documentation has multiple options for the characters you want to restrict the field to. You can even make your own character sets! Check out the link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset

Comment: How would I adjust this so that my character set is dynamically created based on the language set of the device?

Comment: CSLocalizedString.LocalizedString() returns a localized string for the current language. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corespotlight/cslocalizedstring/1616401-localizedstring?changes=latest_minor Try that. NSLocale could help too. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale?language=objc

Comment: If what you want isn't there you could just make a list of a bunch of characters from a site like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Answer (score 0):

You could check it like that (is Swift):

```
let charactersSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")
if yourString.rangeOfCharacter(from: charactersSet.inverted) != nil {
    print("string contains special characters")
}
```

Comment: Can I dynamically change the array of characters based on the iPad language, for example, what if I wanted German, how would I adjust that array of characters?

Comment: In the other answer there is already a very good advice about NSLocalizedString. Just put in some string characters set for all base languages you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can try some thing like:

```
NSString *inputString = @"abc0129yourcontent";
BOOL success = [inputString isMatchedByRegex:@"^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$"];
```

You can convert in Swift if required.